# Extend a list using last element to match longer list in LINQ zip

Tags: c#, linq, list, haskell, f#

I have two collections:

```
p = [ a, b ]
v = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

I want to process the following tuples:

```
[ [a,1], [b,2], [b,3], [b,4], [b,5] ]
```

My current code is:

```
p.zip(v, (x,y) => { ... })
```

But of course I only end up processing:

```
[ [a,1], [b,2] ]
```

It feels like I want to create an infinite list of last(p), overlayed by p, which we then zip with v. Something like:

```
extend(p).zip( v, ... )
```

Where extend(IEnumerable list) returns

```
[ a, b, b, b, ..., b ] // Infinite/generated sequence
```

I think I can write extend() as an enumerator on list that when exhausted, keeps returning the last element, ad infinitum.

What I'm interested in knowing is if there's a functional way of creating extend, by composing existing functions. I'd be happy to see it expressed in Haskell/F#, even if those functions don't exist in LINQ. I'm encouraging myself to think functionally.

I have looked through https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-List.html for likely atoms but don't see anything that might create what I need.

Thank you!

Edit:

I've reduced the problem further:

```
extend(list) = list.Concat( repeat(list.Last()) )

where repeat(T item) returns [ item, item, ..., item ]
```

I am now searching LINQ and Haskell for existing implementations of something like "repeat".

Comment: do you always want to extend the last element of p to match it with all remaining elements of v? What if v has less elements than p?

Comment: @HW Good question. Strictly speaking, I've handled that case separately. It's an error condition. The full monty solution would always be at least as long as p, with default values supplied for missing v elements. That would be brilliant to see that done as well. I ought to try and figure that out myself, but would be happy to see pointers. Thank you!

Comment: You can also avoid creating the extended list by defining your own zip function.  E.g.  `zlr (x:xs) [y] = (x,y) : zlr xs [y]  ;
zlr (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y) : zlr xs ys  ;
zlr [] _ = []`

Comment: Is anyone able to explain the downvote? Did I not do enough research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Staying in the .Net/C# world:

You could use something like:

```
var almostInfinite = items.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(items.Last(), Int32.MaxValue));
```

but it will not yield a really infinite sequence.

Writting your own `Extend` method isn't hard, either:

```
IEnumerable<T> Extend<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    // error checking omitted 
    var e = source.GetEnumerator();
    T last = default(T);
    while(e.MoveNext())
        yield return last = e.Current;
    while(true)
        yield return last;
}
```

You could also create another version of `Zip`. Take a look at morelinq's [`Zip`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Zip.cs?r=03799046f7e508c90c3733212bf6da57e55191ad), which handles source sequences of different sizes.

Comment: almostInfinite meets requirements, thank you! We have similar implementations of extend, though I return nothing if source is empty. 
Thank you for the reference to morelinq.

Answer (score 4):

A solution in Haskell:

```
> let extend = foldr (\x xs -> x : if null xs then repeat x else xs) []
```

A few tests:

```
> extend []
[]
> take 10 $ extend [1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
> take 10 $ extend [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```

The above does not use `last`, so that we do not hold a reference to the whole input list to `extend` -- in this way it can be garbage collected.

Of course, explicit recursion would also work:

```
extend :: [a] -> [a]
extend []     = []
extend [x]    = repeat x
extend (x:xs) = x : extend xs
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `repeat` you have mentioned could be implemented as follows:

```
let repeat item = 
    Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> item)
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a place to go exploring in Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell (*ghci*)

```
> let p = ["A", "B", "C"]
> let v = [1..]
> let zipExtending a = zip (a ++ repeat (last a))
```

then

```
> mapM_ print $ take 5 $ zipExtending p v
("A",1)
("B",2)
("C",3)
("C",4)
("C",5)
>
```

Using Linq you could create extensions

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<A> extend<A>(this IEnumerable<A> a, int count) {
        return a.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Max(0, count - a.Count())).Select(_ => a.Last()));
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<A, B>> zipExtendingBoth<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> a, IEnumerable<B> b) {
        if(!a.Any() || !b.Any())
            return new Tuple<A, B> [] { };
        return a.extend(b.Count()).Zip(b.extend(a.Count()), Tuple.Create);
    }
}
```

then

```
var p = new string [] { "A", "B", "C" };
var v = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
foreach(var e in p.zipExtendingBoth(v))
    Console.Write("{0}, {1}\n", e.Item1, e.Item2);
```

with result

```
A, 1
B, 2
C, 3
C, 4
C, 5
```

if your "right" list is infinite (first can't be) then

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<A, B>> zipWithInfinite<A, B>(this IEnumerable<A> a, IEnumerable<B> b) {
        if(!a.Any() || !b.Any())
            return new Tuple<A, B> [] { };
        var max_a_index = a.Count() - 1;
        return b.Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(a.ElementAt(Math.Min(i, max_a_index)), x));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for reuse of existing functions, but your code has shown me how to avoid using yield break, which I'm very happy about. If v needs to be extended, it is extended using f(p_elem) when p_elem is the corresponding item from p. I neglected to mention this.

Comment: I've just seen the Haskell part to your reply (was it an edit?) - that is also very neat. Thank you.